# Getting string after the first _

Tags: javascript

I have a String such as ABC_DEF_GHI.

Using JavaScript I need to get everything after the first _ (that is, DEF_GHI in this case). There could be any number of _ in the String.

If I do something like

```
var str = "ABC_DEF_GHI_JKL";
var n = str.lastIndexOf('_');
var output = str.substring(n + 1);
```

This would give me everything after the last underscore. However, I need everything after the first underscore. Couldn't find a method such as firstIndexOf which would give me everything after the first _

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should replace your `lastIndexOf()` by `indexOf()` which will take the first occurrence

```js
var str = "ABC_DEF_GHI_JKL";
var n = str.indexOf('_');
var output = str.substring(n + 1);
console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var str = "ABC_DEF_GHI",
pos = str.indexOf("_");
result = str.slice(pos+1);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Not sure why you got a down-vote here, so I'll up-vote you.  As someone here is been a down-vote troll.

Comment: @Keith He may have been downvoted because he didn't give any explanation, which is not a good practice. But somewhere I agree with you, people who downvote should add a comment explaining why they downvote...

Answer (score 0):

```js
console.log("ABC_DEF_GHI_JKL".split('_').slice(1).join('_'));
```

The above simply split's your string into an array, splitting at the _, and then drops the first array element, and then joins them back together with _.

Comment: And the downvote was for?..  Using indexOf is not a great solution anyway.  What if you later wanted to get everything after the second _.  Down-voting this just shows how narrow minded some on Stack Overflow are.  Or at least have the manners to explain your down-vote.

Comment: The requirement is to get the part after the first underscore. The canonical solution for that requirement is to use `indexOf`. If the requirement changes, so does the code. There is no point in adding code that solves theoretical, future requirements. Especially when that code is more expensive than the straight-forward solution.

Comment: @str  This was the requirement ->  Using JavaScript I need to get everything after the first _ (that is, DEF_GHI in this case).   The requirement wasn't to correct his code.  Read his post again.  If English is not your native tongue then I'll forgive you.  Down voting for no reason just make people into down voting trolls.  Not good for Stack Overflow.

Comment: English is indeed not my native tongue, but I understand the question perfectly fine. But what I do not understand is the point of your comment. Both your answer and using `indexOf` produce the same result, namely "DEF_GHI_JKL". Are you referring to the fact that the question and the code do not match ("DEF_GHI_JKL" vs. "DEF_GHI")? Still, over-engineering for theoretical requirements is useless.

Comment: @str  No my solution worked so what was the problem?.  None.. It answered the OP's question spot on, no need of down-vote, not that complicated really.  What is there not to understand?.  And there certainly wasn't any over-engineering, it was the simplest answer and less chance of error.

Comment: "it was the simplest answer and less chance of error" I strongly disagree about that.

Comment: @str  We will just have to agree to dis agree on that one then.  I'll just go and see what answers to go and down-vote on then, as that appears to be the Stack Overflow way.  Find someone who has tried to help someone else, and then down-vote them.

Comment: @str I agree that the Keith's solution is "more expensive". But it's the only point that may be debatable, and from my point of view  it doesn't justify a downvote. Conversely, I don't agree that "adding code that solves theoretical, future requirements" would be bad. As a long-time developer (tens of years) I'm firmly of the opinion that it's _always_ a good idea not to quickly choose the most obvious and easy solution, but have some thoughts about how it may be more general, _even with no immediate need_. Based on that, I think it's a good thing to report this kind of advice to beginners.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is

```js
var str = "ABC_DEF_GHI",
    pos = str.indexOf("_");
 result = str.slice(pos+1);
 console.log(result);
```

Comment: I'm not going to down-vote you here, like some people do.  But I will point out the result is slightly wrong.

Comment: @Keith Oh yes you are right. Thanks for pointing out. I corrected.